# is it possible to resize/hide Window Standard Dialog ("choose file to upload" window)?

Tags: windows, handle

The "choose file to upload" window which pops up when the browse button is clicked in the file input element on a web page.

Is it possible to hide/resize this "choose file to upload" window using user32 lib functions like `ShowWindow` etc. I tried using `ShowWindow` by providing the handle of the "choose file to upload" window but it didn't work.

Is it possible to work on this windows? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: are you trying to influence (change a standard dialog) the client browser from the server? I very much hope this does not work!

Comment: Oh.. and what programming language/environment is this based on?

Comment: I am using VB6 and I want to just make it invisible. If that is not possible can I just resize it? Is this possible?

Comment: Just to clarify, I am working on a windows application which is coded in VB6. I have to access the browser through this application. While doing this I want to hide/resize the standard dialog ("choose file to upload" pop up window)

Comment: ShowWindow on the window handle of the dialog should work, what happend when you did that? nothing? or did the dialog exit?

Comment: when I tried using ShowWindow on the window handle of the dialog absolutely nothing happened. The "choose file to upload" dialog remained open and without any activity. I had to close it manually after some time.

Comment: Not too certain I understand your requirements... Have you considered avoiding the problem altogether by not using the browser, but instead an http-library?

Comment: Oh I haven't tried not using the browser. In fact I am not aware of Http-library. I will have to do a bit of reading on that now. If you have any information about using http-library instead of the browser.. please enlighten me..

Comment: WHY do you want to hide a file chooser? Wait until the user has finished using the chooser and closes it by canceling or selecting Open.

Comment: Actually, it was a problem I was facing when I was trying to develop an E-filing functionality. I could not wait for the user to choose because the process was supposed to be automated. And the security features of the browser doesn't allow to programatically assign a path to the input field of type "File". So I had tried to do the entire process of clicking on the "browse" button and choosing a file through my program. While doing this I didn't want the user to see the "choose file to upload" pop up on his screen. I couldnt hide it so I wanted to know if i could resize it or so...

Comment: This is never going to work. If you just want to upload a file why don't you go that. I see no reason to invoke browsers!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could try http://www.plupload.com/ which bypasses the need to open the file chooser windows and instead uses HTML5 or Flash to upload.